# XSLT enrich text in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have this XML request :

```
 <soapenv:Body>
      <compte>
         <login>Lilian00</login>
         **<password>?</password>**
         <name>Lilian</name>
      </v1:compte>
 </soapenv:Body>
```

I want to use XSLT to enrich the `<password>?</password>` filed, to get this result :

```
 <soapenv:Body>
      <compte>
         <login>Lilian00</login>
         **<password>admin</password>**
         <name>Lilian</name>
      </v1:compte>
 </soapenv:Body>
```

I try this but it dosen't work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    >
    <xsl:param name="password" />


    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/soapenv:Body/compte/password">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$password" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone help me please, how can i do it ?

Comment: Does it work if you simply remove the first slash from the template match? ie. do `<xsl:template match="soapenv:Body/compte/password">`

Comment: Thnx @TimC No it doesn't work, is the XSLT file correct ? because i've never used XSLT

Comment: Your XML is not well formed: `<compte>` and `</v1:compte>` do not match. If `compte`is in a namespace, then your 2nd template will not match it. There are also no namespace declarations binding either prefix  to a namespace URI.

Comment: I removed the namespace <compte></compte> but it dosen't work, i think i have problem with my XSLT

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a complete version of the XML, that has all namespace declarations present? (i.e. xmlns:soap="..." and xmlns:v1="..."). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with small adjustments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    >
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="password" select="'foo'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/soapenv:Body/compte/password">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | ./*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$password" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltransform.net/jxDigU7